# How to redirect from one html page to another html using Springboot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I am making a TicTacToe Application using Springboot and Thymeleaf. But I am facing issues to redirect my `index.html` to `message.html`

### Here is my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>

<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-main.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app-layout.css" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/tic-tac-toe.png" />

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="navbar-brand"> <img alt="Brand"
                    src="images/tic-tac-toe.png" /> Tic Tac Toe
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="game-area panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <h4 class="game-status">
                <span th:if="${game.getPlayerState().isInProgress()}"
                    class="label label-default"> Your turn. Think very carefully
                    and click a square when ready.</span> <span
                    th:if="${game.getPlayerState().isWin()}"
                    class="label label-success"> YOU WIN! Your superior
                    intellect prevailed and assured a sound victory. Click here to <a
                    href="/message">view your reward</a>
                </span> <span th:if="${game.getPlayerState().isLoss()}"
                    class="label label-danger"> You've lost. Better luck next
                    time!</span> <span th:if="${game.getPlayerState().isDraw()}"
                    class="label label-info"> Mheh! A smelly draw. Beats losing
                    though, right?</span>
            </h4>

            <table class="board">
                <tr th:each="row : ${game.getBoard().getTiles()}" class="board-row">
                    <td th:each="tile : ${row}">
                        <div th:id="${tile.getId()}" class="board-row-tile"
                            th:classappend="${!tile.isEmpty()} ? ${tile} + '-value' : (${!game.isGameOver()} ? 'available')"
                            th:text="${tile}">&nbsp;</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <form id="form_mark_tile" th:action="@{/}" method="POST"
                class="form-inline">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input name="player_go_first" type="checkbox"
                        th:checked="${game.isPlayerGoFirst()}" /> Play First</label>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-new-game-wrap">
                    <a id="btn-new-game" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"
                        href="javascript:void(0);" role="button">New Game</a>
                </div>

                <input id="is_game_over" type="hidden"
                    th:value="${game.isGameOver()}" /> <input id="tile_id"
                    name="tile_id" type="hidden" value="" /> <input id="new_game"
                    name="new_game" type="hidden" value="" />
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

### Here is my TicTacToeController

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("game")
public class TicTacToeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(@ModelAttribute("game") Game game) {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String markTile(@ModelAttribute("game") Game game, @RequestParam("tile_id") String tileId,
        @RequestParam(value = "new_game", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean newGame,
        @RequestParam(value = "player_go_first", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean playerGoFirst) {

    if (newGame) {
        game.reset();
        game.setPlayerGoFirst(playerGoFirst);
        if (!playerGoFirst) {
            // give computer a small advantage by always placing X in the center as its
            // first move
            game.markTile("1-1");
        }
    } else {
        game.markTile(tileId); // Player Turn

        game.markTileRandom(); // Computer Turn
    }

    return "index";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/message")
public String message() {
    return "redirect:/message.html";
}

@ModelAttribute("game")
public Game populateGame() {
    return new Game();
}
```

}

Can someone guide me with a piece of code on how to redirect it to a new HTML page, `message.html`. I am not passing any specific data from `index.html`. I am getting the following error while running on the `href` attribute.

### **> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly i suggest you to make use of ErrorController interface, so you can track better where your errors are.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

As for your error, I assume your other controller endpoints are working fine (if it's not the case, check @ComponentScan related issues), and also that you have a message.html template on your templates folder (in case you don't have your message.html then surely you get 404 error). But assuming you have all this:

1. Go http://localhost:8080/message.html directly from your browser and see how it fails. So from here we know that it's not a problem caused by your redirect
2. If it's not a problem from the redirect, it means the problem is that this URL can't be resolved. So at some point Spring doesn't know where to find your page (because no body told him :( )
3. So now you move your "messaga.html" file to "src/main/resources/static/" folder and... Tadaaa ! magically works.

Why it works now ? Basically because of where Spring looks for static content by default (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

If you want to keep it as a static page, it has no sense to go /message endpoint for a redirect to /message.html, you can directly set your href attr like /message.html

If you want your message.html page to don't be static, make it a template and return it with ModelAndView or whatever.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view

In case you still want to redirect more stuff.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward